# Count total uploaded file in laravel 9 while uploading multiple file

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, multiple-file-upload

I'm using API for storing images/files in DB. Users can select multiple files. Before storing those files in DB, count the total number and limit the user to uploading more than 4 files.

I have attached the function below

```
public function apiUserGalleryImageStore(Request $request) {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|string',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:1024',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 422,
                'message' => $validator->errors(),
                'data' => null
            ], 422);
        } else {
            if(!$request->file('image')) {
                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 422,
                    'message' => 'No file founds',
                    'data' => null
                ], 422);
            } else {
                $images = $request->file('image');
                if(count($images) > 3) {
                    return response()->json([
                        'status' => 422,
                        'message' => 'Only 2 files are allowed',
                        'data' => null
                    ], 422);
                } else {
                    foreach ($images as $img) {
                        $imageName = hexdec(uniqid()) . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalName();
                        $directory = 'support-files/images/user/gallery/';
                        $img->move($directory, $imageName);
                        $imageUrl = $directory . $imageName;
                        $ok = UserGallery::insert([
                            'user_id' => 1,
                            'photo_name' => $imageUrl,
                            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                        ]);
                        if ($ok == true) {
                            return response()->json([
                                'status' => 200,
                                'error' => 'Photo uploaded successfully',
                                'data' => null
                            ], 200);
                        } else {
                            return response()->json([
                                'status' => 422,
                                'error' => 'Try again',
                                'data' => null
                            ], 422);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm stuck on **count($images) > 3** Here I want a out put like 2,3,4

I have problem with **'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:1024',**

It should be like

```
**'image'   => 'required|array|max:2',
  'image.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:1024',**
```

Comment: Hi ! Please post code that you have tried it with. Where are you stuck? Also see [about (home)work questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @PeterPointer, thanks for your help, now I have attached code and expected output

Comment: Your solution works fine, if you want to allow 4 files, just put `count($images) > 4` instead

Comment: @Lk77, this count($images) show error like 'count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile given in file'

Comment: @Shahabuddin you need to submit an array of images : `image[0]`, `image[1]`..., here you seems to submit an individual image using the `image` key, if you do that, you will likely only get the last one

Comment: Also, is this a problem with Laravel 8 or 9? Keep in mind that v8 is EOL, so please plan an upgrade to at least v9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is this :

```php
public function apiUserGalleryImageStore(Request $request) {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|string',
            'image'   => 'required|array|min:1|max:4',
            'image.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:1024',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'status'  => 422,
                'message' => $validator->errors(),
                'data'    => null,
            ], 422);
        } else
        {
            $images = $request->file('image');
            $ok = [];
            foreach ($images as $img)
            {
                $imageName = hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$img->getClientOriginalName();
                $directory = 'support-files/images/user/gallery/';
                $img->move($directory, $imageName);
                $imageUrl = $directory.$imageName;
                $ok[] = UserGallery::insert([
                    'user_id'    => 1,
                    'photo_name' => $imageUrl,
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                ]);
            }
            // handle here the response, after the foreach
            if(in_array(false, $ok)) {
               // some files errored
            } else {
               // all files completed
            }
        }
    }
```

simply check if you got an array of images like you expect

Also, check out laravel custom requests, which will allow you to put your validation logic away from your controller, and make things easier